# Why to use extension methods if source code is available instead of inheritance

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance

I just read in msdn/books that extension methods are useful to add methods to existing classes if the existing class source code is not available , however I have noticed in some very good written open source codes that extension methods are still used along with with inheritance (abstract, interface) on classes that have source code written by the author himself/herself.

This is just general question , no source code here.

Comment: Extension methods on interfaces can be handy.

Comment: Your question could be a better fit for the site if you removed the last paragraph, but instead asked what the problem would be with adding methods to a derived type, rather than extension methods.  Curiously, though, none of the answers given note the real problem: if you derive a class `DerivedFoo:BaseFoo` and your code uses any of `DerivedFoo`'s features on passed-in objects, it won't be able to accept instances of `BaseFoo`, even if those new features could be implemented entirely in terms of `BaseFoo`'s public members.

Answer (score 3):

A common reason is dependency management: Let's say you have a fairly general class `User` and a not-so-general class `GravatarImage`. Now it might make sense to be able to call `SomeUser.GravatarImage()` instead of `GravatarImage.ImageForUser(SomeUser)`. This is not only convenience; in a large project, it might be hard for other programmers to find out the 'right' way to do something. IntelliSense will help a lot here.

However, the User class is a "backend" class and should not need to know anything about images, views, gravatars or URLs, so you want to keep dependencies clean.

A similar argument applies to LINQ, which basically consists of extension methods. These extension methods, extend the collection interfaces, so you can create a lot of functionality with very small interfaces. Implementing a new kind of `IEnumerable` is very easy, yet you gain all the functionality that is provided by LINQ.

The `IEnumerable` interface, to stick to the example, doesn't allow much more than getting an enumerator. Instead of asking each implementor to provide a `Count` method, you can call the extension method which will accomplish the same.

It is noteworthy, however, that a method like `IEnumerable.Count()` can be very slow (it has to touch every element), whereas a direct implementation of the underlying class could be as simple as returning a simple int.

Comment: IEnumerable.Count() is a little smarter than people give it credit for. If the underlying collection is an `IList` or `Array`, it returns the `Count` or `Length` property respectively..

Comment: That is interesting, I didn't know that, thanks! I've seen it happen with database cursors, so instead of asking the DB to count the elements, the entire table/collection would be iterated, which was rather catastrophic in terms of performance ;-)

Comment: SomeUser.GravatarImage() instead GravatarImage.ImageForUser(SomeUser).so adding feature to User class without disturbing it and make it easier for other programmers  to find right functionality associated with specific entity in very large project.

Comment: *"so adding feature to a class without disturbing it"* - pretty much the definition of mixins :) just saying!

Comment: @MattDavey Isn't entirely correct, `ICollection<T>`/`ICollection` that are special cased. | The lack of covariance on `ICollection<T>` has a weird consequence: If your static type is `IEnumerable<Base>` but the collection is say a `List<Derived>` the special case won't trigger, and `Count()` will be slow.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the answers already here are great: I love using extensions for optional behavior, and on interfaces.  There are a couple of other good reasons.

**Avoiding abstract method overloads**.  Consider the following interface:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    User GetUser(int userId);
    User GetUser(int userId, bool includeProfilePic);
}
```

We can see how it might be useful to optionally include the profile pic when getting a user from a `IUserService`.  But, with both methods on the interface, they could be implemented in totally different ways (something this simple *probably* wouldn't, but I run across this problem a lot).  Using extension methods, overloads **cannot** have divergent behavior:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    User GetUser(int userId, bool includeProfilePic);
}

public static class UserServiceExtensions
{
    public static User GetUser(this IUserService userService, int userId)
    {
        return userService.GetUser(userId, false);
    }
}
```

**Respect encapsulation.**  If you have a bit of additional functionality that you want to put on a class, but it does not need any access to internal members of the class to function, and holds no state, then using an extension method is desirable.  The fewer things that know about a classes internal members and state the less coupling you will have, and the easier it will be to maintain code in the long run.

**A downside: you can't Moq Extension Methods**
A lot of times this doesn't matter.  It means that, in order to mock out behavior behind an extension method, you usually need to know how the extension method works, and mock the virtual methods it calls.  This couples your tests to an implementation of the extension method.  This is just annoying if your extension method is simple and unlikely to ever change.  This is pretty bad if your extension method encapsulates some complex set of calls.  For that reason, I usually **only use extension methods for relatively simple behaviors**.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, providing extension methods for an **interface** is usually an attempt at approximating* [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).

> > A mixin can also be viewed as an interface with implemented methods.

Although C# does not support mixins, providing extension methods to an interface class that others can implement is a nice way of "bolting on" functionality.

Here's a real-world example of a simple interface with bolted on functionality delivered as a mixin:

```
public interface IRandomNumberGenerator
{
    Int32 NextInt();
}

public static class RandomNumberGeneratorExtensions
{
    public static Double NextDouble(this IRandomNumberGenerator instance)
    {
        return (Double)Int32.MaxValue / (Double)instance.NextInt();
    }
}

// Now any class which implements IRandomNumberGenerator will get the NextDouble() method for free...
```

* *The big difference between C#'s approximation of mixins and the real thing is that in supported languages mixins can contain private state, where as extension methods on interfaces in C# can obviously only access public state.*

Answer (score 1):

A good way to think of extension methods is like a plugin-type architecture - they give you the ability to include/exclude functionality for a particular type instance. To answer your question specifically:

> Why to use extension methods if source code is available instead of inheritance

The simplest answer to that would be **for optional functionality**. The most common, and probably the most important, reason for using extension methods is being able to extend a particular type without changing any core functionality. Deriving new types for the sake of adding a couple of methods is overkill, even if you had control over the source it would make *more* sense to make the type `partial` instead. Extension methods tend to be used to solve problems for particular scenarios and don't really merit going into the core code base. However, should you find yourself using them all over the place then that's a good indicator that your probably not using them correctly.

For example, consider the following extension:

```
var epochTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToEpochTime();
```

`ToEpochTime` would return me the date time as [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). This would be useful as an alternative way of generating a timestamp or serializing the date. However, it's quite a specific function so it wouldn't make sense being part of `DateTime` but by making it an *extension* method it allows me to simply include this type of functionality if & when required.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of disadvantages I can think of with subclassing as an alternative to extension methods:

1. It can be excessive if you only want to add a couple of lightweight methods.
2. It can create problems if you already have a complex inheritance structure (especially if your class already has subclasses), or intend to have one in future.

I often use extension methods for bridging boundaries between namespaces in a way that increases readability and maintains separation of concerns. For example `myObject.GetDatabaseEntity()` reads quite nicely, but the code for `GetDatabaseEntity()` should be in the database section of the code, not in my business logic. By putting this code in an extension method I can keep everything where it belongs without adding the complexity of subclassing.

Additionally, if `myObject` was instantiated in my business logic before being passed to the database code, then the business logic would need to include the database namespace. I prefer to have each module's responsibilities clearly demarcated, and would prefer my business logic to know as little as possible about the database.

There are also a couple of tricks that extension methods are useful for (some of which have been mentioned already in other answers):

1. They can be applied to interfaces (LINQ uses this a lot).
2. They can be applied to enums.
3. They can be used as event handlers if you create them with the correct signature. (Not that I'd recommend doing this as it can lead to confusion, but it can save you from storing references to objects that you would otherwise need to stick in a collection somewhere - watch out for leaks!)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a somewhat specialized case, but I've found extension methods useful when providing "rules" of various types to existing classes.

Say you have a classe `SomeDataContainer`, with lots of members and data, and you want to export certain pieces of that data in some cases, and other pieces in other cases.

You could do something like this in `SomeDataContainer`:

```
if(ShouldIncludeDataXyz()){
    exportXyz();
}

(...) 

private bool ShouldIncludeDataXyz(){
    // rules here
}

private void ExportXyz(){ (...) }
```

... but I've found that this sometimes gets messy, especially if you have lots of classes, and many rules, etc.

What I've done in some cases, is to place the rules in separate classes, with one "rule class" for each "data class", and create the rules as extention classes.

This just gives me a hierarchy of rules in one place, separated from the core data - a separation I find useful anyway.

The resulting code would still be similar to the above:

```
// This now calls an extention method, which can be found
// in eg. "SomeDataContainerRules.cs", along with other similar
// "rules"-classes:
if(this.ShouldIncludeDataXyz()){ 
    exportXyz();
}
```